# CSS Moved Div Problem

Tags: css, sidebar

On my website http://nebkat.com/beta/index.php I added a sidebar. On the homepage there are two posts. The problem is that the second one always goes under the sidebar content. How do I move it up without using margins(example:margin-top: -50px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float your <div id="content"> to the left? That works in FF 3

Answer (score 0):

There is a DIV with style="clear: both" in between your two posts.  By playing around, I deleted that div and added style="clear: left" to the second post.  So, perhaps try adding "clear: left;" to a CSS class that you use for your post header.  The class you are assigning to this div is mainbar_header so you could just add a clear:left to that.  The div inbetween is causing the spacing issue, not the sidebar.

Comment: I noticed that although I thought it could be fixed without removing/changing it.